# Why ifnull() return DECIMAL instead of BIGINT in MariaDB 10.1+?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, ifnull

Why ifnull() return DECIMAL instead of BIGINT in MariaDB 10.1?

For example:

Query:

```
select a, ifnull(b, 1) from table;
```

10.0.22-MariaDB:

`ifnull(b, 1)` type is `BIGINT`

10.1.37-MariaDB:

`ifnull(b, 1)` type is `DECIMAL`

Moreover, in both versions the return type of this query is the same:

```
select 1; //type is BIGINT
```

Why `ifnull()` convert `BIGINT` to `DECIMAL`?

Comment: what is the actual data type of column 'b' in 'table'?

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe TINYINT UNSIGNED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem, see the example:

```sql
MariaDB [test]> SELECT VERSION();
Field   1:  `VERSION()`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       VAR_STRING
Collation:  utf8_general_ci (33)
Length:     72
Max_length: 24
Decimals:   31
Flags:      NOT_NULL 

+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.38-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    ->   `bigint` BIGINT,
    ->   `decimal` DECIMAL(5, 2)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO `test`
    ->   (`bigint`, `decimal`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (NULL, NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT 1;
Field   1:  `1`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     1
Max_length: 1
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL BINARY NUM 

+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT
    ->   IFNULL(`bigint`, 1) `bigint`,
    ->   IFNULL(`decimal`, 1) `decimal`
    -> FROM
    ->   `test`;
Field   1:  `bigint`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     20
Max_length: 1
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL BINARY NUM 

Field   2:  `decimal`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       NEWDECIMAL
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     7
Max_length: 4
Decimals:   2
Flags:      NOT_NULL BINARY NUM 

+--------+---------+
| bigint | decimal |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |    1.00 |
+--------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Sorry, data type of column 'b' is TINYINT UNSIGNED

Comment: @Songe: See [MDEV-10171: Wrong field type for COALESCE with unsigned int](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10171).

Comment: @wchiquito - How did you get that debugging output?

Comment: @RickJames: `$ mysql --column-type-info`, see [mysql Command-line Client](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql-command-line-client/).

Answer (score 0):

The default return type  will result from comparasion of the both type values passed to the function, there is some order of the returned types: integer before bigint

```
TYPE (X,Y) = IFNULL(type X , type Y).
```

where the decimal is more general than bigin in your case.

I suppose there are some changes regarding the both version of Mysql as of how to handle the default return type.